# React.js and Laravel

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, reactjs

Can I make a front end with React and back end with

> Laravel

? Or React is only for

> Node.js

back end? 
If it possible, is it wise?

Comment: Why not? ReactJS is just a JSX templating engine that interacts with data.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy because ReactJS needs NodeJS to be installed...

Comment: I don't believe that to be the case.

Comment: @JamesTomatov What are you really asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use React with Laravel.

Check out this repo: https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-laravel
Looks like someone already took care of all the heavy lifting involved.

Comment: If you want server-side rendering and the ability to render components with Blade statements it's one of the more popular ones. However, you DON'T need it to use React - you can start using React as per usual with Laravel Mix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very simple to make backend with laravel and front end on reactjs. Laravel providers Scaffolding options which is very to use. You can use following commands

```
php artisan preset react
```

after installing laravel in the project directory.For more details please visit:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/frontend#using-react.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the react js with laravel. For that you can use a ui package in laravel.

> composer require laravel/ui

And after that to install react js in laravel.

> php artisan ui react

Now you are open to make components in react js in laravel itself.
you can follow the link https://www.laravelcode.com/post/how-to-install-reactjs-in-laravel